# SSIS: use a table to provide a single SQL Server 2012 query and DB2 query whose outputs will be inserted into a single SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

My best attempt at visualizing this:

```
ForEach row in dbo.runThese 

**** Start Loop

(grab select statements from sql table)


dbo.runThese
```

Output:

```
ID   db2_script                           sql_script
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    'select count(\*) from db2_cstmr'    'select count(*) from sql_cstmr'
```

(Run each script on an individual connection to the DB2 and SQL Server database)

(create a combined string with each result)

149, 149

(Insert the combined results into a SQL Server table)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.storeResults
VALUES (149,149)

**** End Loop
```

Comment: My first thought is that you can do it with a script task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three different ways to do this, but I'll provide the one I see is the most elegant. I will split the tasks based on location within the package:

**1.    Variables**

- New variable "Statements" of Object data type, which will hold a list of db2 and sql server statements
- db2_script: String
- sql_script: String
- id: int32

**2.    Control Flow**

- Execute SQL Task: Get all the records (sql statements) into the object variable using something like: SELECT id, db2_script, sql_script FROM dbo.StatementsToExecute. You need to set ResultSet property of the component to "Full result set" and configure the object variable in the Result Set pane
- For Each Loop: using the object variable as enumerator (Foreach From Variable Enumerator) in the Collection pane, and assigning into db2_script, sql_script and id variables in the Variable Mapping pane
- Data Flow component (see next)

**3.    Data Flow**

- OLEDB Source for DB2 database: specify variable db2_script for source statement (Data access mode: SQL command from variable)
- OLEDB Source for SQL Server database: specify variable sql_script for source statement (Data access mode: SQL command from variable)
- Edit both sources with Advanced Editor, got to "Input and Output Properties" tab, click on "OLE DB Source Output", set IsSorted=True, click on "OLE DB Source Output"->"Output Columns"->db2_count/sql_count
- MERGE: merge both sources into one single pipeline and two different output columns
- OLEDB Target: map db2_count and sql_count to the target columns

**Note:** you would need to provide aliases for the Counts in each Select statement (e.g. SELECT COUNT(*) AS db2_count FROM ...) because they will give names to the columns in the Data Flow's pipeline. Another way is to edit in advanced mode both sources and give ad-hoc names